# Webservice throws internal server error when webbrowser control is used

Tags: c#, web-services, browser

I have a web service, created using C#. For some reason, it seems to throw a 500 internal server error whenever I invoke my exposed method. I set some breakpoints and found the following line is what does it:

```
m_Browser = new WebBrowser();
```

Any idea why this line would cause my service to crash? The WebBrowser control is in the System.Windows.Forms namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably because as the [documentation clearly states it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

> The WebBrowser class can only be used
>   in threads set to single thread
>   apartment (STA) mode. To use this
>   class, ensure that your Main method is
>   marked with the STAThreadAttribute
>   attribute.

while a [web service runs in a multi thread apartment mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163544.aspx) (MTA). This same article shows a hack that could be used to run your web service in an STA mode but the performance of doing so might decrease.

Clearly a `WebBrowser` control is not meant to be used in a web service but in a client application with a GUI. So usually when you are trying to use something into a scenario that this something is not meant for, there's a price to pay.